# Mixing tank differential equation for mass

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> A mixing tank with constant volume $V_0$ and flow rate $k$ is initially  filled with pure water.  If the inflow concentration is a constant $c_{in}$ for $0\le t < T$, and is then zero afterwards,  calculate  the  mass  of  chemical  in  the  tank  at  time  $2T$. Hint: use  the Heaviside step function

This is a bit tricky and I am not sure what to do. Since the volume is constant $V_0$, we will get flow rate in = flow rate out, so $f_{in} = f_{out} = k $ right?

Using heaviside, I get $\text{Concentration in rate} = c_{in} - c_{in}H(t - T)$

Therefore,

$\text{Mass in rate}  = k \cdot c_{in} (1 - H(t - T))$

$\text{Mass out rate} = \displaystyle \frac{m(t) \cdot k}{V_0}$

So is the general formula for rate of change of mass

> $dm/dt = k \cdot c_{in} (1 - H(t - T)) - \displaystyle \frac{m(t) \cdot k}{V_0}$

How does one solve this? We dont have initial condition either?

Comment: In-flow of what?  What are the units of $k$?  The question is a bit confusing.  At any rate, we know the volume of the tank and we know it's initially filled with pure water so can't we use the density of water or some such quantity to determine $m(0)$?  Presumably a Laplace transform will do the trick where solving the ODE is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dm}{dt}=q_{in} - q_{out}$$

For $0 \leq t \leq T$
$$q_{in}=kc_{in}$$
$$q_{out}=\frac{km}{V_0}$$

So, the governing equation is $$\frac{dm}{dt}=kc_{in}-\frac{km}{V_0}$$
Since, $m(0)=0$, the solution is $$e^{\frac{k}{V_0}t}m=kc_{in}t$$

Thus, $$m_T=m(T)=e^{-\frac{k}{V_0}T}kc_{in}T$$
Then, from $T\leq t$, $q_{in}=0$. So,
$$m=m_Te^{-\frac{k}{V_0}t}$$